# How to get access to my ftp server through internet

Tags: ftp

I have been able to create my ftp server with vsftpd and I can get access to it locally, I mean without internet...but I want to have access to it over tcp or internet...help?

Comment: There is no clear answer to that as there might be a lot of difficulties in your way. For instance, your machine could be sitting behind a NAT router and the ports are not being forwarded. If you are going to forward ports, make sure that the server is absolutely tight in terms of security. Google "How to secure my ubuntu server" or similar searches to find guides on that.

Comment: Hello, I'm not able to answer this. Not sure about tethering and android using ftp. I have only setup tethering on androids before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some software for example filezilla for connecting to your ftp server.
download it from there:
[filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a complex question.
Yes, you are correct, it is easy to do when you are on same network inside house, work, etc...

The vague answer is that if you have a router, you will have to get logged into it, open a port to be able to get connected, but that may still be a problem because of ISP provider changing IP Addresses on you randomly.
You will probably have to use a [online dns service](https://www.noip.com/free) as well as possibly a few other tricks.

Depending on what your needs are a cloud drive service is much easier solution.

Comment: about the router thing...I don't have one...instead I use a samsung phone over usb for internet access....any solution to that?....

Answer (score 0):

Just read your comment about the samsung phone.

This app says it makes it possible to forward ports on a phone tethering connection. It may be what you need. I have no direct experience using it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bherbst.net&hl=en

--
Original answer:

To help you out, we need more information. Please provide us with answers to the following:

Output of ifconfig on the ftp server:

```
ifconfig
```

Do you have access to the configuration of your network router?

Is this going to be a publicly accessable FTP, or do you want to limit access and is security a concern?